# Is there still an Actionscript3 library available that supports XMP Access and/or parses XMP Metadata?

Tags: actionscript-3, metadata, xmp, metadata-extractor

I know there is an Adobe XMP SDK Kit available, but that does not support AS3 any longer.
Some years ago (before Harman took over AS3) Adobe provided the **as3_xmp_file **abd **XMPCore**.lib

The links provided by [Jeffry Houser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133840/jeffryhouser) at this SO post [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017919/working-example-for-as3-xmp-library) do no longer work.

I already know how to parse EXIF Metadata with AS3, but before going into the pain of parsing XMP Metadata structures myself or diving into Java or C# I thought I should ask the stackoverflow community:

Is there any AS3 Lib available that supports handling of XMP Metadata in JPG Files?

I found the old as3_xmp_file, but could not find the requested XMPCore lib. So I am stuck.
I couldn't find any topic related to XMP Metadata in the Harman developer forum.

Perhaps I did not use the correct keywords searching for a lib, but I did not find anything promising with a Google search yet.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://code.google.com/archive/p/as3-xmp-file/

Comment: Thank you, I found that and as I already wrote, the Class references a Lib (XMPCore lib) that no longer is available. I couldn't find it with wayback neither.

So what I'm still missing is exactly that lib.